# Custom iOS button class isn't displaying at runtime

Tags: iphone, ios, cgrect

I have a custom button class that I generated using Paintcode. It looks like this:

```
//
//  TGCustomConfirmButton.m
//  Indego
//
//  Created by 
//  Copyright
//

#import "TGCustomConfirmButton.h"

@implementation TGCustomConfirmButton

+ (TGCustomConfirmButton *)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)type
{
  return [super buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  NSLog(@"drawRect enter");

  //// General Declarations
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  //// Color Declarations
  UIColor* strokeColor =    [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.143 green: 0.429 blue: 0 
                                            alpha: 1];
  UIColor* shadowColor2 =   [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.712 green: 0.972 blue: 0.489 
                                            alpha: 1];
  UIColor* gradientColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.391 green: 0.925 blue: 0.262 
                                            alpha: 1];
  UIColor* gradientColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.052 green: 0.454 blue: 0.044 
                                            alpha: 1];
  UIColor* fillColor2 =     [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.833 green: 0.833 blue: 0.833 
                                            alpha: 1];
  UIColor* gradientColor3 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 1 blue: 1 
                                            alpha: 1];

  //// Gradient Declarations
  NSArray* greenHighlightColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   (id)gradientColor.CGColor,
                                   (id)[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.221 green: 0.69 
                                            blue: 0.153 alpha: 1].CGColor,
                                   (id)gradientColor2.CGColor, nil];
  CGFloat greenHighlightLocations[] = {0, 0.23, 0.58};
  CGGradientRef greenHighlight = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, 
                                            (__bridge CFArrayRef)greenHighlightColors,
                                              greenHighlightLocations);
  NSArray* innerShadow002Colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   (id)fillColor2.CGColor,
                                   (id)[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.917 green: 0.917 
                                            blue: 0.917 alpha: 1].CGColor,
                                   (id)gradientColor3.CGColor, nil];
  CGFloat innerShadow002Locations[] = {0, 0, 0.66};
  CGGradientRef innerShadow002 = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, 
                                            (__bridge CFArrayRef)innerShadow002Colors,
                                             innerShadow002Locations);

  //// Shadow Declarations
  UIColor* shadow3 = shadowColor2;
  CGSize shadow3Offset = CGSizeMake(0.1, 3.1);
  CGFloat shadow3BlurRadius = 0;

  //// Rounded Rectangle 2 Drawing
  UIBezierPath* roundedRectangle2Path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: 
                                        CGRectMake(36, 913, 577, 126) cornerRadius: 11];
  CGContextSaveGState(context);
  [roundedRectangle2Path addClip];
  CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, innerShadow002, CGPointMake(324.5, 913),
                                             CGPointMake(324.5, 1039), 0);
  CGContextRestoreGState(context);


  //// Rounded Rectangle Drawing
  UIBezierPath* roundedRectanglePath=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: 
                                     CGRectMake(48.5, 926, 550, 86.5) cornerRadius: 6];
  CGContextSaveGState(context);
  [roundedRectanglePath addClip];
  CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, greenHighlight, CGPointMake(323.5, 926),
                                    CGPointMake(323.5, 1012.5), 0);
  CGContextRestoreGState(context);

  ////// Rounded Rectangle Inner Shadow
  CGRect roundedRectangleBorderRect = CGRectInset([roundedRectanglePath bounds], 
                                            -shadow3BlurRadius, -shadow3BlurRadius);
  roundedRectangleBorderRect = CGRectOffset(roundedRectangleBorderRect, 
                                        -shadow3Offset.width, -shadow3Offset.height);
  roundedRectangleBorderRect = CGRectInset(CGRectUnion(roundedRectangleBorderRect,
                                             [roundedRectanglePath bounds]), -1, -1);

  UIBezierPath* roundedRectangleNegativePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:
                                             roundedRectangleBorderRect];
  [roundedRectangleNegativePath appendPath: roundedRectanglePath];
  roundedRectangleNegativePath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;

  CGContextSaveGState(context);
  {
    CGFloat xOffset = shadow3Offset.width 
                      + round(roundedRectangleBorderRect.size.width);
    CGFloat yOffset = shadow3Offset.height;
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context,
                                CGSizeMake(xOffset + copysign(0.1, xOffset),
                                             yOffset + copysign(0.1, yOffset)),
                                shadow3BlurRadius,
                                shadow3.CGColor);

    [roundedRectanglePath addClip];
    CGAffineTransform transform = 
                    CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation
                          (-round(roundedRectangleBorderRect.size.width), 0);
    [roundedRectangleNegativePath applyTransform: transform];
    [[UIColor grayColor] setFill];
    [roundedRectangleNegativePath fill];
  }
  CGContextRestoreGState(context);

  [strokeColor setStroke];
  roundedRectanglePath.lineWidth = 1.5;
  [roundedRectanglePath stroke];


  //// Cleanup
  CGGradientRelease(greenHighlight);
  CGGradientRelease(innerShadow002);
  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

  NSLog(@"drawRect exit");

}

@end
```

This code is being applied to a UIButton, whose type has been set to custom. The button is in the app in two places (and lots more as dev goes on), once inside a view placed underneath a UITableView and once inside a normal, plane Jane UIViewController. In both cases the label text for the buttons renders at run time, but the design of the button itself is nowhere to be seen.

There are lots of tutorials out there for using PaintCode to draw things (which I need no help with) but zero on how to implement a custom button class once you've created it. I've done this before using non-PaintCode created classes, and I *pretty sure* I have it right. Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: UIButton is not really suitable for subclassing, try to subclass UIControl instead for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Kaan Degeblu : bad hint, just don't use the convenience method to init it

Comment: `UIButton is not really suitable for subclassing` Simply not true. Apple will specifically state in the docs when a class is not suitable for subclassing.

Comment: @sosborn I'm also surprised that Apple Doc's do not say anything about subclassing, but I've seen it discussed a few times. Also http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW26

Comment: Subclassing it is fine. If you have problems dub classing a button than you simply aren't doing it correctly.

Comment: UIButton is a class cluster and with class clusters - you should use composition rather than inheritance

Answer (score 2):

See my comment, also from the Apple Docs for:

```
+ (id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType
```

> This method is a convenience constructor for creating button objects with specific configurations. It you subclass UIButton, this method does not return an instance of your subclass. If you want to create an instance of a specific subclass, you must alloc/init the button directly.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not seeing the background color/gradient is because the CGPoints on the drawRect code is hardcoded. So the strokes and fills will probably not end up happening in the button rect.

I replaced :

CGRectMake(36, 913, 577, 126) with rect,

CGPointMake(324.5, 913) with rect.origin,

CGPointMake(323.5, 1012.5) with CGPointMake(rect.origin.x+ rect.size.width, rect.origin.y+rect.size.height)

and I am pretty much able to get the background fill and gradient. You might need to do some some more tweaking based on your requirements.

I used the button, by adding a button to the xib and changing its class to TGCustomConfirmButton

Answer (score 0):

Avoid buttonWithType

```
TGCustomConfirmButton *button = [[TGCustomConfirmButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

---

OR do it like this

```
+ (TGCustomConfirmButton *)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)type {
  return type==UIButtonTypeCustom ? [[self alloc] init] : [super buttonType:type];
}
```

USAGE:

```
TGCustomConfirmButton *button = [TGCustomConfirmButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity and for others looking for PaintCode help, here was our solution.

In PaintCode you can create any canvas size you like to work in. I was under the impression that, like Illustrator, PaintCode would only render art where there actually was art. Instead, it attempts to render everything in your canvas in the space provided. So, in my case, it was attempting to render a 640x1136 canvas into a 300x44 button. In a sense, it was working; the white from the top of my canvas was rendering into the canvas of the button.

In short, when creating buttons and other controls in PaintCode, you need to be mindful of the size of the element you're designing. Even as it is, a 300x44 PaintCode design won't render perfectly into a button of that size. I've found I need to plan for a few lost pixels on the right and bottom of the element I'm calling the custom class on. I'll fiddle more with it and probably resolve this too.

Anyway, thanks for all the answers. As I said, I hope this helps someone.